# Como "chamar" um conjunto de codigos no HTML? (tipo uma navbar)

Tags: php, html, css, node.js

To fazendo um site, e em cada pagina preciso repetir varias partes do codigo, como por exemplo a navbar

Há como encurtar isso no proprio html, "chamando" o codigo?
Ou só usando algo no back? (eu sei que com php da mas queria algo em node)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Veja o link no box do topo para uma solução server-side, porém independente de linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 0):

Da pra fazer isso utilziando a biblioteca EJS https://ejs.co/ através dela você consegue enviar dados do node e consumir no seu HTML, além de conseguir fazer também essa parte de componentização e re-utilização de código.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).